# How to get the environment variable from local using @Value in spring?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, environment-variables

I set a key inside my environment (in bash_profile file) called 'FLAG'(the value is 'true'). I'm trying to get his value by using annotation Value.
so far i tried to do this:

```
@Value("\${FLAG}")
 private lateinit var process_flag: String
```

but no success, I'm getting an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'FLAG' in string value "${FLAG}"
```

*should I add any import\annotation to the class?

Comment: How are you running the code? Is it running as *you*, in a process where *your* `.bash_profile` file was applied?

Comment: I'm using intellij so i guess its running on my local. i guess it doesn't know where is the bash_profile is..im using mac

Comment: See this question for how to verify the environment variables of another process: [Environment variables of a running process on Unix?](https://serverfault.com/a/66366)

Answer (score 2):

Try providing a default value in case the variable is not defined:

```
@Value("${some_property:default_value}")
private String key;
```

Otherwise you'll get an exception whenever some_property is not defined.

If that doesn't work you can also try:

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {

    @Value("#{environment.SOME_KEY_PROPERTY}")
    private String key;

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:** maybe it will sound funny but the solution for me was to turn off and on the intellij, of course after declare the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Spring cannot see what is inside bash_profile file it rather gives access to Jvm system properties. Try below:

java ....  -DFLAG=${FLAG}

"DFLAG" is jvm system property and "flag" is the value in bash_profile file.

Answer (score 0):

For the custom source locations try to add this annotation into your config:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:{whatever_you_want_path}")
```